# Permission error for pig script on hadoop

Tags: permissions, hadoop, apache-pig

I have setup a hadoop cluster and it's running quite fine. On top of it, I am working with pig scripts.

However I'm getting the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=tavasthi, access=WRITE, inode="home":dsslmn:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
```

Can someone give and pointers to rectify this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have permission in HDFS to save to the folder `home`. Your user, `tavasthi` is not the user `dsslmn`, and therefore does not have permission to write to the `home` folder (`rwxr-xr-x` denotes that only the user has write permissions).

can you post the code where you are trying to use the pig STORE command, to include the path, and let us know whether the path to this output folder exists, and whether your user has the permissions to write to it.

Comment: I was using dump command and redirecting it to my unix filesystem. So, fairly I am not dealing with store command in pig right now.

Comment: I think dump still creates a file on HDFS, that it then streams the contents to your stdout.

Comment: why is it trying to write over home directory. Can somebody give pointers about which property to fix here. 
I tried changing pig.temp.dir=/tmp but it is still trying to access home inode.

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the bug. 
Apparently, I used /home/{user.name}/hadoop/tmp as temporary storage directory as hadoop.tmp.dir

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve similar issue by using secure impersonation feature
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/Secure_Impersonation.html

Following this code snippet

```
UserGroupInformation ugi = 
                    UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser("hduser", UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser());
            ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
                public Void run() throws Exception {
                    Configuration jobconf = new Configuration();
        jobconf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://server:hdfsport");
        jobconf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hduser");
        jobconf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "server:jobtracker port");
                 String[] args = new String[] { "data/input", "data/output" };
                ToolRunner.run(jobconf, WordCount.class.newInstance(), args);
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

The remote (windows desktop host in my case) login user id should be added in `core-site.xml` as mentioned [in the URL](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/stable/Secure_Impersonation.html)

Comment: Your "in the URL" link is dead, any chance you have a similar link?